# When does sys.stdin await input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

What are the rules that determine whether `sys.stdin` awaits user input or not? For example:

```
>>> sys.stdin
# <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> "".join(sys.stdin)
# <awaiting input...>
```

The second line awaits input even though I'm not "calling" `sys.stdin` or anything, so how does python know and what are the rules for when it waits?

Finally, is it possible to enter in `sys.stdin` without a trailing `\n` ? For example:

```
>>> "".join(sys.stdin)
hello
'hello\n'
```

To exit I have to do <kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>. Can I get the input without the `\n` or so I just need to always do a `rstrip()` at the end or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second use case is using the fact that file objects are iterators; it's implicitly calling `sys.stdin`'s `__next__` method over and over until it raises `StopIteration`. Since it runs to completion, not just a single line, it won't return until `sys.stdin` is closed (typically by the other side). So the answer is what you thought, you just didn't realize that invoking the iterator protocol counts as a form of "calling".

If you just want a single *line* of input, without the newline at the end, just use [the `input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (that implicitly pulls the result from `sys.stdin`, but only a single line, it doesn't wait until it's closed). Otherwise, you're stuck stripping the newlines manually.

Comment: very interesting, thanks. `>>> x=sys.stdin.__next__()` `asdf` `>>> x` `'asdf\n'`

Comment: also, does `sys.stdin` open `/dev/stdin`, or is handled separately? Where could I find out more info about that?

Comment: @carl.hiass: It's set up for it by the OS when it launches the process. `/dev/stdin` is an OS-specific feature, and just another way to access the `stdin` of the process, but the process itself is not responsible for opening it itself.

Comment: @carl.hiass: Note: It's fairly rare to invoke `__next__` directly. Typically, you iterate implicitly, or more rarely, use the `next` top-level built-in, e.g. `next(sys.stdin)`. In the case of files, you can also do `sys.stdin.readline()` (which isn't identical in behavior, but it's mostly similar modulo some weirdness with `tell`). All of those leave the newline (if any) intact, but it's not exactly hard to add `.rstrip('\n')` to strip it off.